# next.js Cannot read image

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, styled-components

Development environment
・ next.js
・ typescript
・ styled-components

I'm loading the image  in the folder inside pages, but it is not displayed.
Why?

// packege.json

```
{
  "name": "nextapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "9.4.4",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.0.18",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.41",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.7",
    "typescript": "^3.9.6"
  }
}
```

> I added

This is the folder where the images are loaded.

```
import React, { FC } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components”;


const SidebarStyle = styled.nav`
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
width: 175px;
background-color: #F6F7F9;
height: 100vh;
border: solid 1px #ffffff;
`;

export const User: FC = () => {
return (
<SidebarStyle>
  <img src="../../public/images/icon.svg" />
</SidebarStyle>
);
};

export default User;
```

Comment: Should you paste a `tsx` file showing how you load an image?

Comment: how are you importing the file

Answer (score 0):

you need to first import the image then refer it into `<img />`

```
import React, { FC } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components”;
import icon from '../../public/images/icon.svg'

const SidebarStyle = styled.nav`
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
width: 175px;
background-color: #F6F7F9;
height: 100vh;
border: solid 1px #ffffff;
`;

export const User: FC = () => {
return (
 <SidebarStyle>
   <img src={icon} />
 </SidebarStyle>
 );
}

export default User;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add an image to `public/images/icon.svg`, the following code will access the image: [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving)

```
function MyImage() {
  return <img src="/images/icon.svg" alt="my image" />
}

export default MyImage
```